# How accurate are performance measurements in the Rails production log?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance

Today we plan to move our servers from a local VPS hosting service to [storm on demand](http://www.stormondemand.com). The reason for the migration is that SoD has very impressive VPS:es availible and we want to have our databaseserver on servers with great I/O. When testing a few requests on the storm on demand server we get significantly higher request handling times.

We expected latency, since the servers are located in the US and we are located in Europe, but were surprised to see that we got so much higher measurement times in production.log.

Here are some sample output from the production log:

**Old setup**

1 CPU CORE
4GB RAM
100 GB, RAID-10 * SAS 15.000 RPM

PostgreSQL 9.1.5, Rails 3.2.5, Ruby 1.9.3p194

```
Started GET "/top_list" for 83.249.254.229 at 2012-11-14
10:43:15 +0100 Processing by UsersController#user_toplist as HTML Completed
200 OK in 16ms (Views: 0.5ms | ActiveRecord: 6.0ms)
```

**Storm on Demand setup**

64 CORES
256GB RAM
750 GB SSD, RAID 10 SSD

PostgreSQL 9.2.1, Rails 3.2.9, Ruby 1.9.3p327

```
Started GET "/top_list" for 83.249.254.229 at
2012-11-14 11:26:37 +0100 Processing by UsersController#user_toplist as HTML
Completed 200 OK in 164ms (Views: 0.0ms | ActiveRecord: 114.9ms)
```

We also tried a simple benchmark:

```
task :perf_top_list => :environment do
elapsed_time = Benchmark.realtime do
  500.times do
            users = TopRatingUsers.top_rating_users(20)
      end
end
puts elapsed_time
```

end

Basically this is the same request as shown above but instead executed as a rake task. The rake task takes about 5 seconds on the old server and 10 on the new server. This makes the old server twice as fast as the new one compared to ten times faster which the production.log indicated.

The deployed application have the same set up on both servers, what other factors could possibly influence the measurements?

Comment: Those measurements are fairly accurate if you are not multi-threaded. ActiveRecord seems to be taking way more time in the new setup. Are you sure your database server is configured properly?

Comment: We have now tried with the same version of postgresql on both servers as well as the same postgresql.conf. Same results :( . On both servers the rails-app is located on the same server as the database.

Comment: the rails logs show your view time sped up but your AR time dramatically increased. It seems likely there is a configuration, data, or statistics difference in your database instances causing some queries to run much slower. Turn on full statement logging in postgres and find some slow queries, then run explain analyze on those queries.

Comment: Just in case. Every time you restore database you run ANALYZE of course.